# Need to download Expression Blend Sample Beehive Project and other sample Projects

Tags: c#, vb.net, expression-blend, expression-blend-4, beehive

I am learning Expression Blend on Version 4. Every and every code in its user guide are based on Beehive Sample and that sample is not available in Expression Blend. So I was wondering if there is a link from where I can download it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah got answer to my question.

I had downloaded Windows Phone SDK and Blend 4 comes free with it. So I could only make Windows Phone projects in that.

The project I wanted to downloaded are WPF & Silverlight based used in (WPF Projects). When I upgraded my Blend from free to full version (Ultimate i.e. Blend + WorkFlow) I got those projects.

Answer (score 0):

In case you or anyone else is looking for the beehive sampke. I believe it's in the assets of this tutorial series on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/ee426917.aspx